# Duplicate fake image while using an iframe

Tags: html, css

I have created a website, but there is one problem. My Masthead and Footer are position:fixed, and I have a video page. my Video page contains Youtube videos using iframe.

Whenever I scroll down and up, this problem sometimes occurs:

[image: Duplicate fake image while using an iframe]
*Ignore the symbols you can't understand, this is my language :P*

Well, that was my best way to describe the issue.

Any idea how to fix that? I have already tried using the "Object" embed code instead of the iframe, but still, it didn't work and the issue is still hapenning.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Seems more like a rendering issue for your graphics card not updating quickly enough, rather than an inherent issue with your code.

Comment: impossible, my graphic card is really strong. Moreover, i have checked this issue through many computers, about 10 in numbers, and they all had the same problem. The issue happens only if I scroll down and up slowly.

Comment: Same browser each time? We'll need to see code to reproduce this.

Comment: Well, I checked only in Chrome, now I checked in FireFox and now the problem is, the youtube video, comes UPON the Masthead instead of behind it, that's weird >.< I have no idea what to do

Comment: You'll want to set the z-Index of the youtube element to be lower than that of the masthead to fix that.

Comment: I have already tried it. The z-index is set to 0.

Comment: Are you wanting the entire page to scroll or just the video section while the Masthead and footer stay visible?  I use a similar layout on my website where I use SSI's for the header and footer and the main body is only allowed to scroll.  I don't use iFrames though.  Can you post your code so we can check it out?  That will make it easier to come up with a solution.

Comment: Well, what I'm doing is, only the video section will scroll, and the masthead and footer are "Position:fixed" so they are always there. There is no code to post here, it's very simple :s the masthead+footer are position:fixed and the video section is regular Div. I'm using an iframe because that what Youtube provides. I also tried using the Object type that youtube provide, but still, the same problem is occurring. Any idea? and if you wan't a code, which one do you want/need?